Not getting an interview due to institution's fault
I applied for PhD in March using my exam scores. In April the university announced that they would interview candidates whose scores were above a certain threshold. They did send an interview call letter to those eligible candidates. My scores were a little below the threshold, so I accepted my fate.
Today I visited their website for some other reasons and I learned that they lowered the thresholds such that I would now qualify. However, they didn't contact the newly-eligible applicants, they just wrote that newly-eligible applicants may contact them within a week. I didn't see the notice and missed the deadline.
I feel very much unhappy by this. My scores were written in my original application. So when they published a revised cut off list, is it not their duty to check who are now eligible for interviews and send them the interview call letters?
Some of my friends are now telling me that I should've checked their website regularly. But again they (the authority) didn't send any mail stating that they have published a revised cut off list. So there was no reason for me to check the website again and hope that something would change magically!
The admission process of this season is over. What should I do now? Should I mail them asking for an interview?

You might write, explaining the situation, concisely, as you see it, and request an interview. ‘Betrayed’ and ‘demanding’ suggest to me there might be other things in your life to come to terms with.

What country? Did they say exams scores were the only criterion?

Thanks for the comments. There were some minimum eligibility criteria (e.g having certain gpa or higher in last degree) which my application satisfies. Other than that, the only criteria was to satisfy any of those exam scores.

Why do you expect them to actively contact newly eligible applicants? Did they original contact all eligible potential applicants personally?

@VolkerSiegel Yes, they did send the interview call letters to all the original eligible candidates. I mentioned this in my original post. Seems like this point is not clear in the edited post.

Unfortunately, whether it's their fault or not, it's your problem. That's unsatisfactory but it won't be the last time something like that happens to you. If that helps, it happens to everyone once in a while.

@Aruralreader Thanks for the comment. I wrote this post in a somewhat enraged mode. Now after some reflections, I understand that I should not have used words like betray and demand. I have changed those words.

@SoumikMukherjee I see - that's unusual. I would propose the following way to see it: They do not have a perfect application process - but it is much better than usual - they even send individual interview call letters. But it did not really work out, and they needed to make a change. Now somebody had to fix the problem, and did that in the "normal way" - without the individual mails. It makes sense that you may have expected the mails, but I would not really blame them that they just solved the problem, instead of trying to solve it perfectly.

I think there is no harm to contact them, saying that you missed the deadline but you are very interested to the program. Chance is not high, but no harm to try.

Just don't complain or accuse. That would be counterproductive.

@Buffy Thanks, do you think stating my unhappiness can sound like complain or accuse?

@SoumikMukherjee: Yes, definitely. Remember that (a) dealing with complaints and with unhappy people is uncomfortable for most people and (b) they are under no legal obligation to help you. Thus, if your mail makes them uncomfortable, the easiest solution for them will be to "play by the rules" and deny your request. You're asking a stranger for a favor. You want them to fell good about helping you, and you want them to look forward to interacting with you, not dread that interaction.

@SoumikMukherjee Don't state your unhappiness. See this interview as a privilege, not as a right.

You missed your application for a technical reason you can explain. That you are unhappy about it is your personal problem. They did not trick you, they just had a less than perfect application process. They know that, you do not need to explain it to them. Just as they will not blame you for not checking their website. You just want to find out whether they are interested in interviewing you.

They had your contact info, knew you applied, and know what their standards are.  My assumption would be that if they wanted to interview you, they would have contacted you about it.  I have never seen an interview process in which you have to figure out if you meet their requirements and contact a school to schedule an interview.

Agreed; It sounds a bit like they maybe wanted to take someone who didn't meet the original cutoff but was strong in other areas, and to be fair they 'opened' the interview process to more people but never would have actually expected to take on OP. So, in other words, I doubt they really missed out, they just weren't selected for interview.

@BryanKrause Yup -- also doesn't rule out the possibility that the school won't eventually reach out, but it's pretty late for that, at least in the Northern Hemisphere school year.
